# Dojo: dojox.grid.LazyTreeGrid + QueryReadStore - errors when paginating children

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo, treegrid

I'm testing LazyTreeGrid implementation in Dojo. And I have this problem.
When LazyTreeGrid is used with LazyTreeGridStoreModel and QueryReadStore pagination of children nodes sometimes causes errors.

I was trying to only load children of opened nodes and to load only those records that are visible.

Pagination of root records seems to work fine but after opening a node only the first page of children is loaded and the rest is filled with "...". To scroll I'm using mouse wheel.

Tested under: Firefox (9.0.1), Chrome (18.0.1025.152 m), IE9 (9.0.8112.16421)

I opened a ticket in dojo trac. There You can find code examples and screen shots.

-> http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/15155

Answer (score 1):

The URL sent to the server is of the form http://xxx/yyy?start=0&count=25
I think you need to respect the start and count parameters or bad things happen with pagination.  It didn't  look as if your test code did that.